# Force link to open in Chrome

Tags: html

I have a HTML file on my server with a link to it from outlook.

Is there a way in HTML or Javascript to force the page to always open in Chrome. I know the systems have Chrome installed by default.

Comment: Fixed grammar and gave it a more appropriate title

Comment: You can only force it to open in a (system default) browser. You don't have a choice on which browser to use.

Answer (score 4):

Double clicking your file will automatically open it in your default browser. If you'd like it to open in Google Chrome you need to set Chrome as your default browser. 
I don't know of a way in HTML/Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

well holding the shift key down and clicking on the link may do the trick assuming chrome is your default browser