# force link to open firefox instead of safari in mobile

Tags: firefox, browser, hyperlink, responsive

Please forgive my english.

As you may know, Webrtc is not compatible with Safari IOS on iphone.
So I need to force link to open firefox instead of safari.

I found solution for chrome:

```
googlechromes://google.com
```

If I do the same for firefox:

```
firefox://google.com
```

It open firefox but doesn't load the url. It will just display firefox with the previous url I open on my last firefox session.

So I made a search and I found these:

[Force link to open in mobile safari from a web app with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930001/force-link-to-open-in-mobile-safari-from-a-web-app-with-javascript)

[Force link to open in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790376/force-link-to-open-in-chrome)

[iOS Facebook App browser - force link to open in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242946/ios-facebook-app-browser-force-link-to-open-in-safari)

But none of these solutions answer to my specific question.

Can someone already faced same issue?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards

Gauthier

Answer (score 3):

Firefox URL scheme to do that would look like:

```
firefox://open-url?url=https://google.com
```

There is an open in Firefox library that can help with escaping:

```
https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios-open-in-client
```

Firefox also has a bug open to add support in IntentKit

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1399801

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of Safari bookmarks that I use for this type of thing.  These are helpful when I am using Safari, but there is some formatting issue and so I want to quickly/easily open the same page in another iOS browser.  HTH.

**Safari Bookmark Name**:  *Open In Firefox*
**Bookmark URL**:  *javascript:location.href=%22firefox%3A%2F%2Fopen-url%3Furl%3D%22+location.href;*

**Safari Bookmark Name**:  *Open In Chrome*
**Bookmark URL**:
*javascript:location.href=%22googlechrome%22+location.href.substring(4);*